# passing arbitrary html to a popup window

Tags: php, javascript

I am calling my makewindows function from a PHP file like so:

```
echo "<a href='#' onclick=\"makewindows(" . $html . "); return false;\">Click for full description </a></p>";
```

This generates correct html, which results in a popupwindow containing the html from $html. For example(most of the html has been snipped):

```
<a href="#" onclick="makewindows(&quot;<P align=center><SPAN style=\&quot;FONT-FAMILY: Arial\&quot;>&quot;); return false;">Click for more</a>
```

Now, I want to make an image above the link clickable, to display an image instead of html, using the same method.

I made an $imagehtml variable in php like so:

```
$imagehtml = "<img src='".$imageSrc."' >";
```

$imageSrc is the result of another method, but is always without fail a valid url for an image

passing $imageHtml to makewindows should work(the fact that it is not standards complaint html is irelivant, at least as to why what I am trying is failing. The same single line of html in a standalone html file displays in every browser fine.)

this results in the following html:

```
<a href="#" onclick="makewindows(<img src='removed.jpg' >); return false;">
<img src="removed.jpg" width="250" height="250"></a>
```

This completely fails. It has nothing to do with the image path, as no window is created at all. All I am doing is changing the variable passed, surely the window should still be created, regardless of  the contents of the html?

this fails even if trying to pass about:blank, for example defining imagehtml as follows:

```
$imagehtml = "about:blank";
```

results in:

```
<a href="#" onclick="makewindows(about:blank); return false;">Click for full description </a>
```

yet still no window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want something like this:

```
$str = '<img src="...">';

echo '<a href="#" onclick="makewindows('
    . htmlspecialchars(json_encode($str))
    . '); return false;">Click for full description</a></p>';
```

This will do the correct encoding / escaping.

Comment: why is this necessary when the source of the output shows correct html?

Answer (score 0):

You’re probably doing something wrong.

Let’s say you want to pass this HTML to a JavaScript function call inside an HTML attribute:

```
<img src="removed.jpg" width="250" height="250">
```

Then doing this is enough:

```
$html = '<img src="removed.jpg" width="250" height="250">';
echo '<a href="#" onclick="makewindows(' . htmlspecialchars(var_export($html, true), ENT_QUOTES) . '); return false;">Click for full description</a></p>';
```

The [`var_export` function](http://docs.php.net/var_export) converts the value into an (PHP) equivalent expression and the [`htmlspecialchars` function](http://docs.php.net/htmlspecialchars) finally converts the HTML meta characters into character references.

This might not be the most elegant way, but it works.

Comment: why is this necessary when the source of the output shows correct html?

Comment: Yes. Thereby you can use quotes inside the attribute value such as `title="&quot;quoted title&quot;"`